# LESS CSS: How to Create and Reference Associative Lists/Arrays

Tags: css, less, stylus

Coming from Stylus, I'm looking to create a nested array/list structure like this (Stylus), but in LESS:

```
$myicons = {
    steel: "\e826"
    other: "\e826"
    coolstuff: "\e826"
    ...
}

for icon, ascii in $myicons
    .icon-{icon}
        @extend $icon-class
        &:before
            content ascii
```

Looking at the documentation, it appears that no such data structure is available.  Can anyone suggest an approach to create a similar structure, in which I can loop over key/value pairs in LESS?